# Fields with common names in different records

Tags: erlang

I have some records with similar fields, like this:

```
-define(COMMON_FIELDS, common1, common2, common3).
-record(item1, a, b, c, ?COMMON_FIELDS).
-record(item2, x, y, z, ?COMMON_FIELDS).
```

But later I need to write similar code for every record:

```
Record#item1.common1,
Record#item1.common2,
Record#item1.common3
```

and:

```
Record#item2.common1,
Record#item2.common2,
Record#item2.common3
```

Is there way to write one function for access to same fields in different records?

Comment: Why not define a record with all the common fields and then use that record as a field in each of the other records?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to write one function for access to same fields in
>   different records?

1) **Pattern matching in multiple function clauses:**

```
-module(x1).
-export([read/1]).
-define(COMMON_FIELDS, common1, common2, common3).

-record(item1, {x, ?COMMON_FIELDS}).  %Note that you defined your records incorrectly.
-record(item2, {y, ?COMMON_FIELDS}).

read(#item1{common1=C1, common2=C2, common3=C3} = _Item) ->
    io:format("~p, ~p, ~p~n", [C1, C2, C3]);
read(#item2{common1=C1, common2=C2, common3=C3} = _Item) ->
    io:format("~p, ~p, ~p~n", [C1, C2, C3]).
```

...

```
25> c(x1).
{ok,x1}
26> rr(x1).
[item1,item2]

27> A = #item1{x=10, common1="hello", common2="world", common3="goodbye"}.
#item1{x = 10,common1 = "hello",common2 = "world",
       common3 = "goodbye"}

28> B = #item2{y=20, common1="goodbye", common2="mars", common3="hello"}.  
#item2{y = 20,common1 = "goodbye",common2 = "mars",
       common3 = "hello"}

29> x1:read(A).                                                            
"hello", "world", "goodbye"
ok

30> x1:read(B).                                                            
"goodbye", "mars", "hello"
ok
```

Note the export statement--it's a list of length 1, i.e. the module exports one function.  The output shows that the `read()` function can read records of either type.

2) **A case statement**:
If for some reason, by stating *one function* you mean *one function clause*, you can do this:

```
read(Item) ->
    case Item of
        #item1{common1=C1, common2=C2, common3=C3} -> true;
        #item2{common1=C1, common2=C2, common3=C3} -> true
    end,

    io:format("~p, ~p, ~p~n", [C1, C2, C3]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exprecs` parse transform from [parse_transe](https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans).

```
-module(parse).
-compile({parse_transform, exprecs}).

-record(item1, {x, common1, common2}).
-record(item2, {y, common1, common2}).

-export_records([item1, item2]).

-export([p/0]).

f() ->
    R1 = #item1{x=1, common1=foo1, common2=bar1},
    R2 = #item2{y=2, common1=foo2, common2=bar2},

    ['#get-'(Field, Rec) || Field <- [common1, common2], Rec <- [R1, R2]].
```

...

```
1> c(parse).
{ok,parse}
2> parse:f().
[foo1,foo2,bar1,bar2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to factor out the common fields into a single field in each record companies containing a record with all the common data or even a tulple.  Then refactor your code to do all common processing to its own function.

You still need to pattern match every top level record to get the common sub record.  But somewhere you probably want to do the processing specific to each record kind and there you can already match out the common field.

```
-record(common, {c1, c2, c3}).
-record(item1, {a, b, c, com}).
...

process_item(#item1{a=A, b=B, c=C, com=Com}) ->
     process_abc(A, B, C),
     process_common(Com),
     ...;
process_item(#item2{x=X, y=Y ...
```

Data structures like this might also be a indication to use the new [Map](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id75728) data type instead of records.